# Vertically centering in flex-direction: column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I am trying to vertically center the elements on the left side of my page using Flexbox but haven't been able to figure it out. They're organized via `flex-direction: column`, and I am not sure how to center horizontally when this is set. See below for my code and for a live version of my website so far. I've separated the two flex containers into right and left so I can handle and center them separately. I am only dealing with the left side, for now. So, I'll show the CSS for that first.

I've tried `align-items`, `justify-content`, and `align-self` but those haven't worked.

Thanks, in advance!

Live Website: https://huddle-single-landing-page.jordanchude.now.sh/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left-side">
  <img id="huddle" src="https://i.ibb.co/FnJS8vM/logo.png" alt="logo" border="0">
  <img id="illustration" src="https://i.ibb.co/L9HBmDZ/illustration-mockups.png" alt="illustration-mockups" border="0">
</div>
<div class="right-side">
  <p id="headline">Build The Community Your Fans Will Love</p>

  <p id="subtitle">
          Huddle re-imagines the way we build communities. You have a voice, but so does your audience. 
          Create connections with your users as you engage in genuine discussion.
  </p> 

  <button>Register</button>

  <div class="social-icons">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
        <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-1x"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
        <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-1x"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
        <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-1x"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* Left Side */
.left-side {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
    width: 800px;
}

#huddle {
    width: 200px;
    align-self: flex-start; 
}

#illustration {
   width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the look you're going for. Please provide an example or illustration to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no extra height in your container, so there's no free space for centering.

Make this adjustment:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    /* align-items: center */ /* vertically centers both left and right elements */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 100vh; /* child would inherit height through align-content: stretch default */
}

.left-side {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 800px;
    align-self: center; /* vertically centers the flex item */        
    /* justify-content: center; */ /* vertically centers the content of the flex item */
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I was able to center everything. Is there a way to center only certain items? For example, I want "Huddle" to stay in the top left corner but it moves with the illustration below it.

Comment: If you remove everything from `left-side`, except `width: 800px`, and add `display: grid`, that appears to work.

Comment: Got it. I see that the two elements are separated now via grid, but I am still having trouble getting "Huddle" to hover above the illustration near the top left of the container. It actually doesn't need to be the top left of the viewport, specifically, because I want it aligned with the illustration's left side. It just needs to move upwards. I tried using margin-bottom, but that makes the entire page larger and pushes everything downwards.

Comment: I thought you meant the top left corner of the container. You mean the top left corner of the viewport?

Comment: Sorry, I was editing my comment when you sent yours in. Correct, top left of the container.

Comment: Adding my code to your website seems to work, as you request. Maybe you can post a codepen or jsFiddle so we can better see and test the problem.